# A family of functions with an asymptotic maximum

Tags: functions, asymptotics, maxima-minima

Let's define a family of functions indexed by positive integer $n$: $\{ f_n(\cdot)\}$, where $f_n: [0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$. Is there an example of $f_n$ so that the following condition holds for some $x_0$?

(Condition)

For small $n$, it could be that $f_n(x) \geq f_n(x_0)$ for some $x\ne x_0$, but there is $N \in \mathbb{N}$  such that $n \geq N \implies f_n(x) < f_n(x_0)$ for all $x \ne x_0$.

In other words, $x_0$ is the asymptotic maximizer of $f_n(x)$.

Comment: Take a look at $f_n(x)=-(x-A_n)^2+B_n$. The max is at $A_n$ and the max value is $B_n$. You can play with the A's and the B's.

Comment: @zoli Thank you!